# Instant trigger email to new subscribes only in a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, dataextensions, exclusion-script

I have a data extension in SFMC that is being populated with opt-ins from an external source. I would like to trigger an instant welcome email ONLY to anyone who is added to this data extension. How do I go about doing this? I want make sure I don't resend to the anyone who was already on this data extension and has received the email.

Comment: How firm are you on the term "INSTANT".  If you're not ultra familiar with engineering an API to create a triggered send, then you can easily use Journey Builder.  The caveat there is that any automation you run to refresh your DE has a default minimum reoccurrence of 1 hour.  So, there could be a lag of delivery between 1 min & 59 mins depending on the contact.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to either do a Triggered email or an API event for a journey.
Either way, you would have to use APIs to trigger them.

After that, you could use a DE as an exclusion list in the email deployment so you don't send the email twice.

If you are doing it as a journey then just select that people can only enter the journey once.